Is there any "not null" annotation that does the actual job?
I can't seem to find any proper annotation for "not null" that does the job entirely:

@NonNull adds an extra runtime check. I don't want that. I just want a static check at compile time.
@CheckForNull forces the receiver of the value to check for nullability. No thank you. The point is that the sender of the value does not send null in the first place.
@NotNull from javax.validation.constraints doesn't seem to work all the time. Same-class checks are OK, but checks when passing null from another class let null through. (see example below)

MyClass.java
package common.utils;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.FieldDefaults;

@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = lombok.AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class MyClass {
    @NotNull
    MyOtherClass mMyOtherClass;
    
}

MyOtherClass.java
package common.utils;

public class MyOtherClass {
}

MyClasstest.java
package common.utils.results;


import common.utils.MyClass;

public class MyClassTest {
    public void test() {
        new MyClass(null); <-- no warnings in the IDE!
    }
}


I have checked that the corresponding warnings are activated in IntelliJ, per @NotNull, @Nonnull etc. all don't work in IntelliJ IDEA
I am fully aware that @NotNull is only supposed to be an indication, it's not designed for enforcement. Is there any annotation that actually enforces non-nullability at compile time, or at least in the IDE, in most cases?

I cannot reproduce the problem in your code. IntelliJ does report a warning for that code, using JetBrain's NotNull.

@sweeper I have posted my full example. Can you try again and maybe locate what setting I might be missing? eDIT: I clearly mentionned javax.validation.constraints not Jetbrains annotation. Jetbrains annotations are nice, but : 1) they are not universal and 2) have yet another behaviour. I am not against them, but do you know if I can make it work with more mainstream annotations?

You imported javax.validation.constraints.NotNull. I don't think that is configured as a nullability annotation in the default settings. You can click "Configure Annotations" in the settings to add that in (see the answer you linked), or you can use a supported-by-default annotation, like org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull.

What is "yet another behaviour"? Is javax.annotation.Nonnull universal/mainstream enough for you? You need a more objective criteria for this to be answerable.

By "yet another behaviour" I mean that Jetbrain's NotNull succeeds where the one from javax fails in reporting the nullability. In effect, this one works differently from the 3 other annotations I've mentionned. It means that now I need to investigate what Jetbrain's annotation has that the one from javax (and the other ones) don't have.  And I have to convince my team to drop javax and replace with Jetbrains everywhere in our huge codebase. I'm not against it but that's not ideal. I'd rather start by understanding why javax's NotNull "doesn't work". I will try to "configure it" as you said.

The annotation themselves are nothing special. Your IDE is doing all the work reporting problems. You should configure your IDE to recognise the annotations you want to use. For IntelliJ IDEA, how this is done is described in the answer you linked. Go to the inspections settings, find a null-related inspection, click "Configure Annotations", and add the annotation you want to use.

PS: @Sweeper you have effectively answered my question; if you post your answer I will mark it as correct.

The annotations themselves are nothing special (except the one from Lombok, which actually gets processed). Your IDE is doing all the work reporting problems. You should configure your IDE to recognise the annotations you want to use.
For IntelliJ IDEA, you should go to Settings > Editor > Inspections , then  find a null-related inspection, and click "Configure Annotations".

then you can add javax.validation.constraints.NotNull to this list

IntelliJ can also generate runtime checks for you if you want them. You can set this in Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler section of the Settings. (Or if you don't want them, now you know where to turn it off :D)

